# Does Firebase Admin SDK have an API to send a SMS token to a user?

Tags: firebase-authentication

We have a mobile application and end users are authenticated via Firebase.

### Current behaviour

- While onboarding users, we register every user on Firebase with an email and a mobile phone.
- Once the user is created on Firebase we the use the [link generation API generateSignInWithEmailLink](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#generatesigninwithemaillink) and send an email to the users.
- Users click on the email from their mobile phone and it automatically launches the App.

### Desired behaviour

- Instead of sending an authentication link in the email, we would like to use the SMS token validation feature of Firebase
- This is very easily down via a browser based application.
- How do we implement such a feature that on Android/Ios?

### Option

- We provide a custom backend HTTP end point which gets called by the user
- From this backend, we instruct the Firebase Admin SDK to send a new SMS authentication token to the have any endpoint which allows the back end to send a SMS authentication token to the end user's mobile.

Is this possible?  At first glance, I could not find anything in the documentation.

Thanks

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not provide a generalized service for verification via SMS.  You will have to find another service for that.

Comment: I think I was not clear. This is what I was referring to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth . If I do not want to use the Android SDK, then is there any other alternative? Thank you.

Comment: There is no alternative in Firebase.  That SMS auth function is only for phone based authentication and is not a generalized SMS verification service.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Let me clarify further. I want to do a phone based authentication, similar to what `verifyPhoneNumber ` method of the *Firebase Android SDK* does. However, the only difference  - I would like my end user to call a custom back end service as opposed to directly invoking the `verifyPhoneNumber` which would then instruct Firebase to send the verification code to the end user .   Does my scenario fall into a *generalized SMS verification service* ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, there are no generalized APIs for sending SMS messages in this sense.